# How many number of key-value pairs in a map I can store in a Firestore document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
User
--user1
  --fullName: "James Gosling"
  --messages
    --messageId1: true,
    --messageId2: true,
    --messageId3: true
--user2
```

I just want to store the id of each messages inside the user document so that whenever I want to update the fullName of a user, I just have to fetch those message ids and create a batched write to update the user's fullName in User Collection and Messages Collection. So how many number of key-value pairs in a Map field I can store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a fixed limit but Firestore recommends having less than [100 fields per document](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#:%7E:text=Your%20documents%20should%20have%20fewer%20than%20100%20fields.&text=Keep%20in%20mind%20the%20standard,not%20stop%20you%20from%20exceeding.). A document also has a max size limit of `1 MB`.

> By default, Cloud Firestore automatically maintains single-field indexes for each field in a document and each subfield in a map.

Creating many sub-fields with different keys will also index them. You can add [exemptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview?authuser=0&hl=en#single-field_index_exemptions) however your message IDs seem be totally random and I doubt if you'll know them beforehand.

If you just want to store the message IDs, then you can use an array instead:

```
{
  username: "test",
  messageIds: ["messageId1", "messageId2"]
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can store user's UID in the message documents and then update the documents sent by the user so you don't have to worry about the document size limit. This [Gist](https://gist.github.com/DharmarajX24/dc64a9d2d7c86f7cb2f485041317ab27) might be helpful to write that function.

Comment: How many number of message IDs can I store in an array?

Comment: @VinceMelmarYbañez there's no limit on length of array but a document has 1 MB max size limit as mentioned above so you can take that as a limit.